# iOS ARC memory increase constantly

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code. Memory has been constantly increasing,when the `viewDidLoad` method is called.I guess that local variable `data` is not released.But why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wakeup.pcm" ofType:nil]];
NSMutableData *mData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data];

  int readLength = 0;
  while (readLength < mData.length) {
     if (mData.length - readLength > EVERBUFFERLEN) {
        NSData *data = [mData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(readLength, EVERBUFFERLEN)];
        readLength += EVERBUFFERLEN;
        data = nil;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put that while loop in an `@autoreleasepool` have a look at this answer for more reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc

Comment: @Mozilla http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121345/autoreleasepool-in-loop-or-loop-in-autoreleasepool

Comment: Why are you putting the thread to sleep?

Comment: @sbarow How should this help? Obviously the memory foot print increases during multiple executions of `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Umm, not such a good idea to sleep the main thread (on which `viewDidLoad` is called).

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad well if thats the case, the code snippet is not the problem then, but rather why the `ViewController` is not being released no?

Comment: @sbarow Why do you think that it is not released?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad more asking the question from what you said, if memory keeps climbing and `viewDidLoad` is being called multiple times we can assume that multiple `ViewControllers` are being created right? Seeing as though memory isn't going down, those `ViewControllers` aren't being released?

Comment: No, you cannot assume this, because $whatever can cause a higher memory usage. The system memory usage does not mean that there are leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Such a "overall memory meter" does not really help finding leaks. I. e. it can be that `-dataWithContentsOfFile:` requests memory down from the system, but it is not freed after usage. Reasons for that can be that allocating memory from the system is slow and holding unused memory "for the app" can be a cheaper way as long as the memory pressure isn't high.