# The correct way to manage cocoa memory when working with Objective-C from Rust

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rust, ffi

I'm struggling with one issue related to the cocoa foundation memory management. Basically I have a project, written in Rust and I'm using `cocoa-rs` and `objc-rs` to interact with Objective-C. I'm familiar with memory management in CoreFoundation and CocoaFoundation (I've already read the corresponding articles in documentation). I did not have any memory issues when I worked with CoreFoundation functions, but I'm having a lot of problems when I use CocoaFoundation related stuff, it seems that getting any objects from CocoaFoundation leaks memory.

Here is the simplified version of one of the functions which leads to a memory memory:

```
pub fn enumerate_apps()-> Vec<Rc<AppInfo>> {
    let mut apps_list = Vec::new();
    unsafe {
        let shared_workspace: *mut Object = msg_send![class("NSWorkspace"), sharedWorkspace];
        let running_apps: *mut Object = msg_send![shared_workspace, runningApplications];

        let apps_count = msg_send![running_apps, count];
        for i in 0..apps_count {
            let app: *mut Object = msg_send![running_apps, objectAtIndex:i];

            // Those ones are not used at the moment, but I actually need them,
            // I just removed all business logic to keep the example simple and compilable
            // to demonstrate the problem.
            let bundle_url: *mut Object = msg_send![app, bundleURL];
            let app_bundle: *mut Object = msg_send![class("NSBundle"), bundleWithURL:bundle_url];
            let info_dict: *mut Object = msg_send![app_bundle, infoDictionary];

            apps_list.push(Rc::new(AppInfo {
                pid: msg_send![app, processIdentifier],
            }));
        }
    }
    apps_list
}
```

I tried to call this function inside a loop to make the memory leak visible:

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        for i in 0..200 {
            enumerate_apps();
        }
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(5000));
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I can see that it consumes more and more memory over time.

My question is: why? What is the correct way to manage memory in a such FFI code? If I run the same code in XCode, using the plain Objective-C, it works fine and seems that it does not leak memory. Well, the reason why the memory is not leaked in XCode is that ARC is enabled by default. To my knowledge ARC is not enabled when we work with Objective-C from Rust in a such manner, so basically it means that we have to manage memory ourselves. Commenting 3 lines containing `bundle_url`, `app_bundle`, `info_dict` creates an illusion that the memory leak is gone (without commenting them, the process leaks a couple megabytes of memory every 2 seconds), but actually the memory is still leaked, but not that fast.

What I tried:

1. I tried to create an `NSAutoreleasePool` in the beginning of the function and call `autorelease()` for `bundle_url` and `app_bundle` upon creation. Did not help, the memory it still leaked.
2. I tried to call `release()` manually on `bundle_url` and `app_bundle`, did not have any effect.
3. Even tried to call `dealloc()` on them (which I believe is a wrong way), which also did not help to solve my problem.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug in `objc-rs` (I guess this is very unlikely, but who knows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Objective-C ARC is not implemented in `objc-rs`/`cocoa-rs`, you need to follow the [memory management rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), in particular for this question: *You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own*.  That is you should not call `autorelease()`, `release()` or `dealloc()` on any of the returned objects.

What you should do is to [create an NSAutoreleasePool inside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121345/autoreleasepool-in-loop-or-loop-in-autoreleasepool), *and don't touch anything else*. The pool will free all those objects when it is released.

```
pub fn enumerate_apps()-> Vec<Rc<AppInfo>> {
    let mut apps_list = Vec::new();
    unsafe {
        let autoreleasePool: *mut Object = msg_send![class("NSAutoreleasePool"), new];

        // ...
        // all code unchanged
        // ...

        msg_send![autoreleasePool, release];
    }
    apps_list
}
```

---

Why calling `autorelease()`/`release()`/`dealloc()` on `bundle_url`/`app_bundle`/`info_dict` cannot decrease memory? Because it is not just these objects leaking memory. The biggest consumption is the `running_apps` object.

And why explicitly calling `autorelease()`/`release()`/`dealloc()` is wrong? Let's review the ObjC memory management rules, and compare it with normal Rust code (I assume you know how the `Rc<T>` type works):

1. **You own any object you create** — You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”

   - You could think of it like:

     ```
     // Objective-C code:
     NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString new];
     NSMutableString* t = [s mutableCopy];

     // Similar to this in Rust:
     let s: Rc<NSMutableString> = Rc::new(NSMutableString::new());
     let t: Rc<NSMutableString> = Rc::new(s.mutableCopy());
     ```

     Your code never called any method begins with "alloc", "new", "copy" or "mutableCopy", so you don't own any of them. This naming convention is followed by all ObjC APIs.
2. **You can take ownership of an object using retain**.

   - This is similar to having an object `a: Rc<T>`, and then you get a new reference by calling `b = Rc::clone(&a)`. Now `b` also "owns" the original object through reference-counting:

     ```
     // Objective-C code:
     NSMutableString* u = [t retain];

     // Similar to this in Rust:
     let u: Rc<NSMutableString> = Rc::clone(&u);
     ```

     But you never called `retain`, so still you don't own any objects.
3. **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own** — You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a `release` message or an `autorelease` message.

   - In terms of Rust, sending a `-release` message is equivalent to dropping the Rc object.

     ```
     // Objective-C code:
     [u release];

     // Similar to this in Rust:
     drop(u);
     ```
   - `-autorelease` transfers the ownership to the autorelease pool. The most recently allocated NSAutoreleasePool will be found, the ownership of the object be moved into that pool, and we only keep a borrowed reference<sup>(*)</sup>.

     ```
     // Objective-C code:
     NSMutableString* v = [t autorelease];

     // Similar to this in Rust:
     let pool: &NSAutoreleasePool = find_top_autorelease_pool()?;
     let v: &NSMutableString = pool.add_object(t);
     // `t` is passed-by-value, so `pool` now owns `t`.
     // `pool` returns a borrowed reference, 
     // so that we can still access the memory pointed to by `t`,
     // but we no longer own it.
     ```
4. **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**.

   - That is you can never drop the memory through a borrowed reference. Well in Rust it is impossible but Objective-C doesn't have a borrow checker.
5. Additionally, calling `-dealloc` is like explicitly invoking the destructor via `drop(*s)` in Rust. This bypasses the reference-counting mechanism and [is explicitly discouraged](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-DontLinkElementID_4).

Let's recap:

- None of the methods you called (`sharedWorkspace`/`runningApplications`/`objectAtIndex:`/`bundleURL`/`bundleWithURL:`/`infoDictionary`) begins with `alloc`/`new`/`copy`/`mutableCopy`.
- You never called `-retain`.
- *That means everything you've got are borrowed*, by rules 1 and 2.
- *That means you should never call `release()` or `autorelease()`*, by rule 4.

Calling `-release` or `-autorelease` on objects you don't own result in double-free. This may cause SEGFAULT, or no-op, or any undefined behavior.

Why the program leaks like a sieve if we don't provide an NSAutoreleasePool? The `runningApplications`/`bundleWithURL:` methods do allocate objects, but adhering to the Cocoa memory management rule, they call `-autorelease` internally to ensure you don't get owned objects. But if we don't allocate any pools, `-autorelease` can transfer the ownership to nowhere, i.e. those auto-released objects become unowned by anyone, and nobody has the ownership to free them, and thus leaked.

---

(*): The analogy is not perfect, because you could get a new ownership with `[[x autorelease] retain]`. But this detail doesn't matter here.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it works! I tried to create `NSAutoreleasePool` via `cocoa-rs` bindings, but it turned out, that they never call to `release`, so creation `NSAutoreleasePool` leaked memory by itself.

Comment: I'm just wondering, why don't we call `autorelease` for `NSBundle::bundleWithUrl()`? According to documentation, the function may allocate and initialize memory, doesn't it mean that we have to call `autorelease` on it?

Comment: @ScienceSE `NSBundle::bundleWithUrl()` returns an object that is already `-autorelease`d. Calling `-autorelease` again will double-free it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is now solved (I'm now using `NSAutoreleasePool` from `cocoa-rs` and `drain` explicitly). I'm just wondering why did not it work when I tried to call `release` manually on each object. Do the autoreleased objects ignore `release`?